# How to install the package ctablestack.sty for Beamer?

Tags: luatex, installing

I am preparing a presentation with beamer but when I compile with lualatex I have an error indicating that I need the file ctablestack.sty, but when I downloaded the package I only find other files: ctablestack.dtx, ctablestack.ins

Comment: usually you use the package manager that comes with your latex installation, e.g. `tlmgr`.

Comment: as with most latex pakages the .sty would be generated if you ran tex on the .ins file but you should not have to do this, the package is in texlive and miktex so you should install it from your tex package manager

Comment: also ctablestack is a rather specialised package it is rather unlikely that you need it unless you  know you are using it. If the document has `\usepackage{luatexbase}` then probabably you don't need that

Answer (score 1):

as mentionned in the answer by David Carlisle, the correct answer is to add

```
\usepackage{luatexbase}
```

Comment: this isn't really an answer, you most likely do not need `luatexbase` or `ctablestack` but if you use `\usepacackage{luatexbase}` and get no error then you have `ctablestack` installed already as `luatexbase.sty` inputs `ctablestack.sty`